# Menu sub menu hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Description**: I've built a menu which displays a sub-menu when the user hovers over the menu. (The menu uses jQuery). Also, the way my menu is set is that if a user hovers over a certain div on the menu, jQuery takes that div name and appends a sub-menu id, which tells jQuery which sub-menu div to display.

**jQuery used:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav div').hover(function() {
        var menu_name = $(this).attr('id');   //gets current div id
        sub_menu_name = '.sub_' + menu_name;  //creates the sub menu that matches that div menu
        $(sub_menu_name).css('display', 'block');
    }, function () {
        $(sub_menu_name).css('display', 'none');
    });     
});
```

**Jsfiddle link**: Please view:

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net/tech_noob/nXR5Y/1/ to see all the code that I used for this menu.

**Problem**: When the user hovers away from the menu and try's to hover over the sub-menu, the sub-menu also disappears. I would like the sub-menu to stay in place if the user hovers over the sub-menu and disappear only if the user hovers away from either the sub-menu or moves to a new menu link. I would also like to preserve the code structure I used in the HTML if possible (For example, I've seen other menu's where the developer used the sub-menu as a child to the respective menu link parent).

Side Note: the UI in my local host displays the sub-menus under their respective menu links, on jsfiddle, the sub-menus are off. Not sure exactly why but this is a minor issue.

Comment: Have you tried making the sub-menu a child of the main-menu?

Comment: Please consider not to roll your own, but use the tried and tested SuckerFish http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/ It also features nice things such as hoverIntent.

Comment: @maartenmachiels That's a bit overkill isn't it? The plugin has some nice options but there's really no reason to use it for something this simple.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses. MiniRag I have tried doing the sub-menu as child to the menu but It fail. Maarten thanks for the link but I really would like to keep it simple.

Comment: If I have to end up using your link Maarten than I might but I feel that im really close to solving this issue, just need a little guidance :)

Comment: FYI, im working on something for ya, one sec

Comment: Thanks Sp can't wait to learn from you  =)

Comment: @user2569019 Glad you found a solution specific to your needs! Personally I don't see SuckerFish as overkill, since it also handles possible problems such as accessing the menu on mobile devices (1 click = dropdown, 2 clicks = navigate). Also, it's still fairly light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little longer than what you have, but it handles all you should need it too handle as far as menus and submenus, provided you maintain those name-scapes. Should you change names, then you'll need to change code.

## Example

```
//  a little prep work would really help make this easier
//  something like:
var tmrMenu;    //  used to keep submenu open long enough for hover over
//  select only menu items via class name
//  and add data variable containing the element you want
//      you could also hard code this in HTML like: <div data-sub-menu=".sub_menu_1" ...
//      and later select it using something like: $($('menu_1').data('sub-menu'))
$("#nav [class^='menu_']").each(function(i) { $(this).data('subMenu', $('#nav .sub_' + $(this).attr('id'))); })
//  now each menu has its sub-menu directly associated
//  we continue the chain
.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(tmrMenu); // clears hiding timer
    var sub = $(this).data('subMenu');
    $("#nav [class^='sub_menu']").not(sub).hide(); // ensure siblings are hidden
    sub.show();
})
.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    tmrMenu = setTimeout(function() {
        $this.data('subMenu').hide();
    }, 250); // a decent amount of time to reach a sub menu
});

// now a little work on sub-menus
$("#nav [class^='sub_menu']").on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(tmrMenu); // clears hiding timer
})
.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    tmrMenu = setTimeout(function() { $this.hide(); }, 250);
});
```

## Example

The rest is all up to you and the CSS! Hope this helps! Enjoy!

Comment: Wow, Thank you SpYk3HH! Your solution is awesome. I did consider and tried using mouseenter and mouseleave but not with an event nor a timeout like you did. This is a great piece of code to learn from. I'm new to stackoverflow and actually this is my first post ever on a forum for help! Again, thank you and all the guy's that replied to me. Thanks guys!

Comment: @user2569019 Welcome to SO, Start setting up your profile and get ya those free starter points!

Answer (score 2):

You have overcomplicated this for yourself.  This can and should be done with different HTML (embedded ULs) and CSS, no jQuery at all.  Please see [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/nXR5Y/10/), which uses far less code and is CSS-driven.

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu 1
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 2
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 3
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item X</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
    padding: 10px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    padding: 0;
}
#nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    cursor: default;
}
#nav > li {
    font-size: 120%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #ccc000;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 2.2;
}
#nav > li > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 80%;
    display: none;
}
#nav > li:hover > div {
    display: list-item;
}
#nav > li > div > ul {
    background: orange;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: @user2569019, since you stated in your comment to Kuro's answer that the gap is intentional, I have modified my answer so that it shows a gap. For performance reasons, you really should not be using jQuery for this if you can do it with CSS-only.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you can replicate this same exact effect using pure CSS. The problem with your code is that it only applies "display: block" on the sub_menu when you're hovering the mainmenu. And since sub_menu is not even a part of the mainmenus, the function won't happen even if you hover on it.

Just like what MiniRagnarok suggested, having the sub menus as child divs would be the best way to do this.

You can add a generic class to the main menu like "menu" and put a sub menu inside it with the class sub_menu. YOu can make the sub_menu appear using this styles:

```
.menu:hover .sub_menu{
   display: block;
 }
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nXR5Y/8/

You should also adjust the sub menu a bit to the top since the gap is a problem. But if you really need the gap, you can put the sub_menu inside another div and have apply the styles above to that div instead of .sub_menu.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Kuro, the gap is intentional and the issue is that I loose control of the CSS when it comes to the sub_menu. For example, in jsfiddle link you provided, when I hovered over the menu, the sub-menu looses it's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [My Example](https://jsfiddle.net/easywebsitesmaker/wnu4uh5n/#&togetherjs=ocIV3cDmgN). This is small code and run with wordpress.

HTML:

```
<div id="ewm_header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <header id="ewm_header1">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="http://cssmenufree.com" title="logo">
                            <img src="http://cssmenufree.com/img/logo.png" alt="logo" data-retina="http://cssmenufree.com/img/logo@2x.png" width="131" height="21">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-nav right">
                        <nav class="mainnav" id="mainnav">
                            <ul class="menu-wrap anima-bottom">
                                <li class="children">
                                    <a href="#">HOME</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                                        <li class="children">
                                            <a href="#">HOME VERSION 1</a>
                                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                <li class=""><a href="#">HOME DARK</a></li>
                                                <li class=""><a href="#">HOME LIGHT</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class=""><a href="#">HOME VERSION 2</a></li>
                                        <li class=""><a href="#">HOME VERSION 3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="children">
                                    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu" style="margin-left: 0px;">
                                        <li class=""><a href="#">ABOUT VERSION 1</a></li>
                                        <li class=""><a href="#">ABOUT VERSION 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span>You can copy code css. It run with menu in wordpress</span>
```

CSS:

```
#ewm_header {
    background: #011d27;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

#ewm_header a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#ewm_header a:hover {
    color: #11c21d;
}

#ewm_header ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    paddingL 0;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.menu-wrap > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.menu-wrap li ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #011d27;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 200px;
}

.menu-wrap li:hover > ul,
.menu-wrap li ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap li ul li {
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.menu-wrap li ul li ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```